# How to use env file per stage and region?

Tags: serverless-framework

I know that I can use either of the two options below to resolve serverless variables with values from `.env.{stage}` files.

- https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-dotenv-plugin
- https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/environment-variables/

But how would I do if I need my env file to also be per region, e.g. `.env.{stage}.{region}`?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's simply not supported by both of those. Consider creating a PR to add this feature to the plugin or Serverless Framework itself.

I believe adding it to Serverless Framework would be great, as this feature is really useful and also the plugin might be abandoned soon, since Serverless Framework provides almost the same features with native `useDotEnv: true` switch.

If you need this feature quickly, you could always clone the plugin repository, add the feature and then use the plugin from your own copy. You can find out more details in the documentation (search for `./`):
https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/plugins

Answer (score 0):

Could you name each .env file a combination of env+region, and then use that?

Ex:

```
us-east-1.dev.env
us-east-1.prod.env
...
```

Then you could deploy with
`NODE_ENV=us-east-1.prod`, which would give you region + env specific dotenv files.